# Redistribution of remaining percentages in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a hard time getting some excel formulas correct. The goal is to redistribute any "lost" Change in Stake (negative values) as positive additions to other rows (the calculation is based mainly on **Inactive Hours** and each stackholder's original **Stake**

In this example, the "period" is 5 days and `Row 1` controls `28.15%` of the stake.  so

`STAKE PER DAY = 28.15% / 5`

I calculate what percentage is lost during 25 hours of inactivity:

```
(25/24 hours) x 5.63% = ~5.86%
```

In this case `Row 1` *loses* `5.86%` percent for their inactivity, while all other members with lesser inactive hours than 25, get that `5.86%` distributed amongst them **based on their original stake**. So `Row 2` gets `21.93%` **of** `5.86%`, and so forth.

Stak[image]

This formula was making my head spin last night:

```
  =IF(B25<>"",IF(D25="YES",IF([INACTIVE HOURS] > 0, -[@[INACTIVE HOURS]]/24*[@[STAKE PER DAY]], [@[ STAKE]]/($K$40+ SUMPRODUCT([[ STAKE]],[@[INACTIVE HOURS]]/24*[STAKE PER DAY], 0))),0),"")
```

Stayed up real late trying to crack it but the closest I got to getting the totals in **Change In Stake** to sum to `0.00%` (I get `0.16%`) and **Final Adjusted Stake** to sum to `100%` (I get `99.84%`).

There's also more to this problem. Consider there can also be multiple rows with different values for inactive hours.

For example, the row with `28.15%` had 25 inactive hours, Row with 15.71% had 15 inactive hours and Row with `12.44%` had 10 inactive hours.

In that case, only 10 of those hours will be fully distributed away from all 3 of these parties, and redistributed to the parties who had 0 inactive hours. However, the stakeholder with `12.44%` was *only* inactive for 10 hours, as opposed to the stakeholder `28.15%` who was inactive for 25 hours.

Therefore, stakeholder `12.44%` will lose and full redistribute 10 hours worth but will also gain some back from the stakeholders with 15 and 25 hours of inactivity, during which stakeholder `12.44%` was active. Likewise, the 15 hours stackholder is entitled to a proportionate share from the stackholder who was inactive for 10 hours *more* than they were.

Can excel formulas handle this type of calculation? What would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your partial solution is complicating the underlying problem so I would propose a different method.  Reading between the lines the issue is to reduce/increase each stakeholders share by the inactive/active hours.

Calculate an equivalent number of hours from the total hours (share * 5 days * 24 hrs), subtract off the inactive hours, re-base the share on the new lower total.  See the image below.

[image]